# Replacing special characters in a string using regular expression

Tags: regex, string, replace

Good morning,

I want to use RegEx.Replace to replace special characters in a string. I want to make sure I only have alphabetic characters in my string. All I want to do is to remove the non-alphabetic characters.
Some code:

```
    Dim myString as String = "Me & my *buddy* love$ fishing!!!"
myString = RegEx.Replace(myString, "\[!@#$%^&*()+]", "")
```

For some reason this does not work so I must be doing something wrong. Please help!

Comment: You must have meant `[!@#$%^&*()+]`. The ``\`` before the first `[` made it a literal `[`.

Comment: Thank you. Going to test now. That was most probably my mistake.

Comment: BTW, any non-letter can be matched with `\P{L}`. You might want to try `RegEx.Replace(myString, "\P{L}+", "")`

Comment: Now I only see the special characters. All the other characters removed.

Comment: You probably used `\p{L}`.You need `\P{L}`